# PostgreSQL - using variable inside quotes

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, intervals

I am trying to use a variable for an expression like this

```
NOW() - INTERVAL '5 days'
```

But getting errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some.archive() RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
    p_archive_depth CONSTANT VARCHAR := '5 days';
BEGIN

    IF (date(p_table_date) < date(NOW() - INTERVAL p_archive_depth))
    THEN
        RAISE INFO '%', p_table_name;
    END IF;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Also tried without success:

```
'' || p_archive_depth || ''
'' p_archive_depth ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the variable with the data type `interval`

```
DECLARE
    p_archive_depth CONSTANT interval := interval '5 days';
BEGIN 
   IF date(p_table_date) < (now() - p_archive_depth)::date
```

Answer (score 1):

[a_horse_with_no_name's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69222491/2422776) is, of course, correct, but I'd like to offer an alternative to round it out in case you're getting the string value dynamically (e.g., querying it, getting it as an argument from the user, etc). You could take the string value of `'5 DAYS'` and explicitly cast it to an `interval` using the `::` operator:

```
IF (date(p_table_date) < date(NOW() - p_archive_depth::INTERVAL))
    -- Here -----------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Thank you, a casting even better sometime, making code more readable. Also thank you for the correction of my poor English :)